# Go Deferred function call again in error panic block

Tags: go, asynchronous

I think the question is pretty clear once you look at the following setup?

```
config := database.NewConfig()
connection := database.Connect(config)
defer connection.Destroy()

...

err = app.Listen(address)
if err != nil {
    connection.Destroy() // Do i need this?
    panic(err)
}

... // defer connection.Destroy() is called
```

Do i have to call the deferred function in an error case of `panic(err)` because thats in a new block and therefore in a different scope?

Comment: No, that's one of the primary reasons to use `defer`. From [the docs](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Defer_statements): _"A "defer" statement invokes a function whose execution is deferred to the moment the surrounding function returns, either because the surrounding function executed a return statement, reached the end of its function body, **or because the corresponding goroutine is panicking**."_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do i have to call the deferred function in an error case of `panic(err)` because thats in a new block and therefore in a different scope?

No, for two reasons: (1) `defer` operates at the level of the *function*, not the level of the *block* (so in this respect it differs from the scope of local variables); and (2) the invocation happens whenever the surrounding function returns, even if it's "returning" only because it called some function that ended up panicking.

As [the specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Defer_statements) puts it:

> A "defer" statement invokes a function whose execution is deferred to the moment the surrounding function returns, either because the surrounding function executed a return statement, reached the end of its function body, or because the corresponding goroutine is panicking.

(In particular, note that the bit about panicking has to do with the *goroutine* panicking, rather than worrying about exactly which function triggered the panic.)

I recommend bookmarking the specification and consulting it when you have this sort of question; although parts of it are technical, for the most part it's pretty readable.

Comment: "bookmarking the specification and consulting it when you have this sort of question" this is good advice, the go docs are pretty approachable